# Enumerate graphs under edge and symmetry constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I would like to create the set of all directed graphs with *n* vertices where each vertex has *k* direct successors and *k* direct predecessors. *n* and *k* won't be that large, rather around *n* = 8 and *k* = 3. The set includes cyclic and acyclic graphs. Each graph in turn will serve as a template for sampling a large number of weighted graphs.

My interest is in the role of topology motifs so I don't want to sample weights for any two graphs that are symmetric to each other, where *symmetry* means that no permutation of vertices exists in one graph that transforms it into the other.

A naive solution would be to consider the 2 ^ (*n* * (*n* - 1)) adjacency matrices and eliminate all those (most of them) for which direct successor or predecessor constraints are violated. For *n* = 8, that's still few enough bits to represent and simply enumerate each matrix comfortably inside a `uint64_t`.

Keeping track of row counts and column counts would be another improvement, but the real bottleneck will be adding the graph to the result set, at which point we need to test for symmetry against each other graph that's already in the set. For *n* = 8 that would be already more than 40,000 permutations per insert operation.

Could anyone refer me to an algorithm that I could read up on that can do all this in a smarter way? Is there a graph library for C, C++, Java, or Python that already implements such a comprehensive graph generator? Is there a repository where someone has already "tabulated" all graphs for reasonable *n* and *k*?

Comment: This sounds like something that might be in "The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph isomorphism is, in my opinion, not something you should be thinking about implementing yourself. I believe the current state-of-the-art is Brendan McKay's [Nauty](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/) (and associated programs/libraries). It's a bit of a bear to work with, but it may be worth it to avoid doing your own, naive graph isomorphism. Also, it's primarily geared towards undirected graphs, but it can do digraphs as well. You may want to check out the *geng* (which generates undirected graphs) and *directg* (which generates digraphs given an underlying graph) utilities that come with Nauty.

Comment: Thanks, @mhum, at least +1. Looks like Nauty's `geng` does allow constraints on degree (for k = 3 `-d1` as lower and `-D3` for upper). But `directg` won't honor those constraints, and the combinatorics of the conversion rules would be non-trivial: while degree one enforces self, in, and out, and degree three forces all either in or out, for degree two it would depend on the neighbors in a very nauty way, wouldn't it?

Comment: You will probably need to do some fiddling to get this to work. I would probably start with *geng* with -d6 and -D6 to get a list of  6-regular, undirected graphs, then feed those graphs into *directg* and throw out the ones that didn't satisfy indegree and outdegree = 3 for all nodes. Not sure if this is fast enough for you, but I would wager that it would be faster than checking isomorphism on your own.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: Also, note that according to [this](http://school.maths.uwa.edu.au/~gordon/remote/graphs/numbers/n8.html), there are only 11 distinct undirected graphs on 8 vertices with 24 edges (necessary but not sufficient if each node has degree 6).

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than an answer, because it seems like I have missed something in your question.

First of all, is it possible for such a graph to be acyclic?

I am also wondering about your symmetry constraint. Does this not make all such graphs symmetric to one another? Is it allowed to permute rows and columns of the connection-matrix?

For example, if we allow self-connections in the graph, does the following connection-matrix fulfill your conditions?

```
 1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
 1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
 1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
```

Starting from this matrix, is it then not possible to permute the rows and columns of it to obtain all such graphs where all rows and columns have a sum of three?

One example of such a matrix can be obtained from the above matrix `A` in the following way (using MATLAB).

```
>> A(randperm(8),randperm(8))

ans =

     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0
```

PS. In this case I have repeated the command a few times in order to obtain a matrix with only zeros in the diagonal. :)

**Edit**

Ah, I see from your comments that I was not correct. Of course the permutation index must be the same for rows and columns. I at least should have noticed it when I started out with a graph *with self-connections* and obtained one without them after the permutation.

A random isomorphic permutation would instead look like this:

```
idx = randperm(8);
A(idx,idx);
```

which will keep all the self-connections.

Perhaps this could be of some use when the matrices are generated, but it is not at all as useful as I thought it would be.

Comment: Thanks, @user1884905. For k = 3 those graphs will indeed be cyclic. Your idea to permute the matrix is neat. For systematic runs, check `perms`. To test for isomorphisms, the permutation index is the same for rows and columns, so a generator could exclude such identical indices. With some edit's I would upvote this. Note, however, that permuting with distinct row and column indexing would only be necessary, not sufficient to avoid isomorphisms, and the savings from this are not clear to me yet. For n = 3 and k = 2, most results are isomorphs, although for n >> k collisions should drop off.

Comment: @s.bandara Thanks for the comments, I see I was a bit off. I'm still wondering about the acyclic graphs though. Is it not necessary for acyclic graphs to have nodes without successors and nodes without predecessors.

Comment: Good point. I meant to say that cyclic or not is not part of my criteria, but I see now that they all will have cycles.